# Why my tensorflow distributed strategy works sequentially, not parallel?

Tags: tensorflow, multi-gpu

I am trying to achieve a parallel computation with my 4 GPUs and tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy().
I wrote a simple version for this and expected that the result print(y) for each GPU comes out simultaneously. But it seems like the operation is always done sequentially, like replica_y :GPU0, replica_y:GPU1, replica_y:GPU2, replica_y:GPU3. Am I doing something wrong? I am using Python 3.6 and Spyder environment.

```
@tf.function
def train_step(dist_inputs):
    def step_fn(inputs):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y = 0.0
            for j in range(100) :
               y = y + tf.reduce_sum(xs_var) ** inputs
            print(y)
        return y
    y_ = strategy.run(step_fn, args = [dist_inputs] )
    return y_

strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([ [1.], [2.], [3.], [4.] ]).batch(4) 
dist_dataset = strategy.experimental_distribute_dataset(dataset)

with strategy.scope():
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 1E-1)
    xs_var = tf.Variable(tf.ones(2), dtype = tf.float32)
    var_list = [xs_var] 

    for inputs in dist_dataset:
        print(inputs)
        y = train_step(inputs)
```

Comment: Are the printing at roughly the same time? Or a significant amount of time between them?

Comment: They are printed with significant difference in time. With increasing range(N) in the for loop, the difference seems increase linearly.

Comment: Could possibly be because you're missing the `tf.distribute.Strategy.reduce()` call?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but adding the .reduce didn't help.